# Unable to install yowsup2 ON WINDOWS (Cannot unpack file / Failed building wheel for python-axolotl-curve25519/ Cannot determine archive format)

Tags: python-2.7, yowsup

Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
    Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

```
C:\Users\nuts>pip install yowsup2
Collecting yowsup2
'''c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py
:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Na
me Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may caus
e the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation
 failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more
information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissi
ngwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py
:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This p
revents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL con
nections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. Fo
r more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#i
nsecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
Collecting python-axolotl>=0.1.35 (from yowsup2)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from yowsup
2)
Requirement already satisfied: argparse in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from y
owsup2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
(from yowsup2)
Collecting pyreadline (from yowsup2)
Collecting python-axolotl-curve25519 (from python-axolotl>=0.1.35->yowsup2)
  Using cached python-axolotl-curve25519-0.1.tar.gz
Collecting protobuf>=3.0.0.b2 (from python-axolotl>=0.1.35->yowsup2)
  Using cached protobuf-3.1.0.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: pycrypto in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from p
ython-axolotl>=0.1.35->yowsup2)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from
 protobuf>=3.0.0.b2->python-axolotl>=0.1.35->yowsup2)
Building wheels for collected packages: python-axolotl-curve25519
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for python-axolotl-curve25519 ... error
  Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\nuts\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-db1wp7\\pyt
hon-axolotl-curve25519\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);co
de=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec')
)" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\nuts\appdata\local\temp\tmpgzldpspip-wheel- --python'''
-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'axolotl_curve25519' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\curve
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\curve\ed25519
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\curve\ed25519\additions
  creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\curve\ed25519\nacl_sha512
  C:\Users\nuts\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9
.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Icurve/ed25519/nacl_inclu
des -Icurve/ed25519/additions -Icurve/ed25519 -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python2
7\PC /Tccurve25519module.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\curve25519module.obj
  curve25519module.c
  curve25519module.c(76) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

  curve25519module.c(78) : error C2065: 'result' : undeclared identifier
  curve25519module.c(82) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
  curve25519module.c(100) : warning C4133: 'return' : incompatible types - from
'PyObject *' to 'int *'
  curve25519module.c(146) : warning C4133: 'initializing' : incompatible types -
 from 'int *(__cdecl *)(PyObject *,PyObject *)' to 'PyCFunction'
  error: command '"C:\Users\nuts\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual
 C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for python-axolotl-curve25519
  Running setup.py clean for python-axolotl-curve25519
Failed to build python-axolotl-curve25519'''
Installing collected packages: python-axolotl-curve25519, protobuf, python-axolo
tl, pyreadline, yowsup2
  Running setup.py install for python-axolotl-curve25519 ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools
, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\nuts\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-db1wp7\\p
ython-axolotl-curve25519\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);
code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec
'))" install --record c:\users\nuts\appdata\local\temp\pip-jnunay-record\instal
l-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:'''
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'axolotl_curve25519' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\curve
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\curve\ed25519
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\curve\ed25519\additions
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\curve\ed25519\nacl_sha512
    C:\Users\nuts\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python
\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Icurve/ed25519/nacl_inc
ludes -Icurve/ed25519/additions -Icurve/ed25519 -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\pytho
n27\PC /Tccurve25519module.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\curve25519module.ob
j'''
    curve25519module.c
    curve25519module.c(76) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'typ
e'
    curve25519module.c(78) : error C2065: 'result' : undeclared identifier
    curve25519module.c(82) : error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
    curve25519module.c(100) : warning C4133: 'return' : incompatible types - fro
m 'PyObject *' to 'int *'
    curve25519module.c(146) : warning C4133: 'initializing' : incompatible types
 - from 'int *(__cdecl *)(PyObject *,PyObject *)' to 'PyCFunction'
    error: command '"C:\Users\nuts\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visu
al C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
```

Command

```
"c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\
\users\\nuts\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-db1wp7\\python-axolotl-curve25519
\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\
r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:
\users\nuts\appdata\local\temp\pip-jnunay-record\install-record.txt --single-ve
rsion-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\nuts\a
ppdata\local\temp\pip-build-db1wp7\python-axolotl-curve25519\
'''
```

Comment: Please format properly and add some more details to your question.